# CSS animation of pseudo element works in Chrome and IE, but is stationary in Safari and Firefox without "position: absolute"

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

Using this HTML:

```
<div class="icon-spinner"> test 1</div>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="icon-spinner nonchrome"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; test 2</div>
</div>
```

And this CSS:

```
.icon-spinner:before{
    animation: spin 0.5s infinite linear;
    -webkit-animation: spin 0.5s infinite linear;
    content:"O";
    font-size: 30px;
}

.parent {
    position: relative;
}

.icon-spinner.nonchrome:before{
    position: absolute;
}

@keyframes spin {
    from {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    from {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
```

As seen in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3j5u8w77/17/), the capital "O" next to "Test 1" spins normally in Chrome 39 and IE 10/11, but is stationary in Safari 8 and Firefox 34. The O next to "test 2" spins in every browser, but its spin is off-center in Firefox.

Safari supposedly doesn't support using CSS animation on pseudo-elements... but then why does setting "position: absolute" fix the "test 2" spin in Safari? And why is the "test 1" spin broken in Firefox? It's supposed to have been the longest supporter of pseudo-element animation.

Since the "test 2" spin works in every browser, how can I fix it in Firefox? On OSX it's smooth, but off-center. While in Windows, it's centered better, but *really* jittery.

And as you can see, I've got several non-breaking spaces in the "test 2" html, to make the content move out of the way of the animation (which is done automatically in "test 1"). How can I avoid the need for that, if possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/3j5u8w77/54/

```
icon-spinner:before{
    animation: spin 0.5s infinite linear;
    -webkit-animation: spin 0.5s infinite linear;
    content:"O";
    font-size: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display:inline-block;
}

.parent {
    position: relative;
}

@keyframes spin {
    from {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    from {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
```

I guess a partial solution. If you use display: inline-block on the pseudo element safari can animate the 'O' just fine without the "position:absolute". As for the off centre spin in firefox if I explicitly set the height to 30px to make sure that firefox knows how big the 'O' is exactly so the rotation is dead centre. But this changes the way that safari rotates the 'O' so this leads me to believe that the 'O' is being seen as different sizes in different browsers due to the way browsers render fonts. Perhaps explicitly set a size for this element and set an exact transform-origin property to ensure the rotation is always centred

Comment: This 99.9% worked! Unfortunately, adding `display: inline-block` makes the animation spin about an axis that's very slightly off-center in Webkit browsers. And since you can't write CSS targeted exclusively at webkit, I don't know if there's any way to solve that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the spinning off-center element can be fixed with one line code:

```
border-radius: 1px;
```