# Simple @keyframes animation works on Chrome but not on Safari

Tags: css, safari, css-animations, keyframe

I've tried everything I can think of, including adding the `-webkit-` prefix to everything and separating out the animation name, duration, etc into different lines. This code is straight from https://codepen.io/pigne/pen/XXNrGj and it works fine in Chrome, but the red text does not appear at all in Safari.

```css
#spin {
  color: red;
}

#spin:after {
  content: "";
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    content: "ipsum";
  }
  10% {
    content: "dolor";
  }
  20% {
    content: "sit";
  }
  30% {
    content: "amet";
  }
  40% {
    content: "consectetur";
  }
  50% {
    content: "adipisicing";
  }
  60% {
    content: "elit";
  }
  70% {
    content: "Hic";
  }
  80% {
    content: "atque";
  }
  90% {
    content: "fuga";
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem <span id="spin"></span>!</p>
```

Comment: It's just probably problem with Safari, nothing you can do about it.

Comment: Btw, this is in a react app if that makes any difference.

Comment: @DennisKozevnikoff Problem is that Safari is the default browser on iphones, where most people will be using this app. Was planning to do this kind of animation on the front page of the site.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS animation of pseudo element works in Chrome and IE, but is stationary in Safari and Firefox without "position: absolute"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27628973/css-animation-of-pseudo-element-works-in-chrome-and-ie-but-is-stationary-in-saf)

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava Thx, I was able to get the snippet in that thread to run in both chrome and safari. Now I have to see if the same logic works with my animation.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I think there's something about the 'content' property in an animation that safari doesn't like.

Comment: dang @AnuragSrivastava, looks like it isn't supported outside of chrome: https://css-tricks.com/animating-the-content-property/ scroll down to "browser support" section